# win2D CanvasControl DrawImage() throughs the error “The Object Has been Closed”?

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

what i have tried is?
i have a class like this

```
public class GridDrawingSession 
{
        CanvasDrawingSession DrawingSession;

        public GridDrawingSession()
        {

        }
        public GridDrawingSession(Object sender, object session)
        {
            this.DrawingSession = session as CanvasDrawingSession;
        }

        public void DrawImage(CanvasBitmap CanvasBitmap,Vector2 Vector)
        {
            this.DrawingSession.DrawImage(CanvasBitmap, Vector);
        }
}
```

And I have Another class like this.

```
class ImageContainner 
{
        CanvasControl DrawArea;
        GridDrawingSession _GridDrawingSession;

        public ImageContainner()
        {
            DrawArea = new CanvasControl();
            DrawArea.Name = "Image layer";

            DrawArea.Loaded += RegisterEvents;
        }

        public void Init(double left, double top, double width, double height)
        {
            DrawArea.Width = width;
            DrawArea.Height = height;
        }
        private void RegisterEvents(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DrawArea.Draw += Canvas_Draw;
        }

      private async void Canvas_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
      {
      GridDrawingSession gridDrawingSession = new GridDrawingSession(sender, args.DrawingSession);
      CanvasBitmap CanvasBitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender,@"Assets\LargeTile.scale-400.png");
                Vector2 Vector = new Vector2();
                Vector.X = 100;
                Vector.Y = 200;
                gridDrawingSession.DrawImage(CanvasBitmap, Vector);
        }
}
```

the above code through the error "The Object has been closed" at "this.DrawingSession.DrawImage(CanvasBitmap, Vector)".I don't Know why this is happening.Can Anyone help me??

Comment: Can you load the bitmap outside of the `Draw` event handler and then remove `async`? I think the `CreateResource` event of the `CanvasControl` is best for loading resources like this.

Comment: its working fine now .I want to call the CreateResources Event whenever CanvasControl is Invalidate?The CanvasControl createResources event wont be called when canvasControl is Invalidate?

Comment: you can't call the `CreateResource` event manually. Normally it's called once, at the begining when it's being loaded.

Comment: If the bitmap has to be loaded multiple times, then I'd recommend loading it in UI thread or any other place then call the `Invalidate` method. Read more in the [doc](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/E_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_UI_Xaml_CanvasControl_CreateResources.htm)